# how convert the number of days obtained with timedelta into integers to use arithmetic operations on it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I'm working with a dataframe and I'd calculated the number of days between two dates

`df4["days"]=df4["today"]-df4["d_0"]`

the result has this format: *1215 days; 907 days; ... ; 1166 days*

I'm trying to use this timedelta variable to calculate a column of compound interest, but first I need to transform it to a numeric variable.

I tried using:
`df4["days"]=pd.to_numeric(df4["days"])`

but the results are numbers with no sense: *104976000000000000; 78364800000000000; ... ; 100742400000000000*

and the idea is to obtain: *1215; 907; ... ; 1166*

Thanks!

Comment: Convert to `total_seconds` and divide by 86400

Comment: `(df4["today"]-df4["d_0"]).dt.days`

Comment: Thanks! I obtained the solution using this: `df4["days"]=df4["days"]/np.timedelta64(1,"D")`